# Autolayout error with NSSplitView When Divider Programmatically Moved

Tags: cocoa, autolayout, nsscrollview

I have a 10.7 app built on 10.9. I'm debugging on 10.9.

My main view has a splitView with two panes: a webview in one, and an NSScrollView in the other.

When the app starts I programmatically move the divider to the right to hide the right-hand pane and the enclosed NSScrollView.

When this happens I get this warning in the console:

> Layout still needs update after calling -[NSScrollView layout]. 
>   NSScrollView or one of its superclasses may have overridden -layout
>   without calling super. Or, something may have dirtied layout in the
>   middle of updating it.  Both are programming errors in Cocoa
>   Autolayout.  The former is pretty likely to arise if some pre-Cocoa
>   Autolayout class had a method called layout, but it should be fixed.

This only happens when the view is first loaded when the app starts. Switching away to a new view, and back, is fine.

I think the problem is that the scroll view is still being drawn when I move the splitView divider, causing the scrollview to be dirtied.

If I comment out the line that moves the divider I do not see the message.

FYI, I did not get the error when building / debugging on 10.8.

From Googling around the consensus seems to be that this is a bug in 10.9 and can be ignored, but I don't like to leave my code with warnings.

Does anyone know how I can fix this? I need to move the code that moves the divider to a point AFTER the view has been fully drawn.

Thanks

Darren.

Comment: have you got any solution?